# Live-action children’s TV show where people developed an aversion to light whilst controlled by some force

Tags: story-identification, aliens, tv

In the 1990s / possibly very early 2000s there was a children’s TV show shown on either BBC1 or ITV in the UK. It would have lasted approximately 25 mins per episode and was shown in the late afternoon approximately 4pm.

All I can remember is that it was live-action (not a cartoon or animation) and that there were grey-coloured, almost balls/brains that started appearing on the ground. If you then approached one of these balls/brains, it would open up and a light would come out of it that caused you to be controlled by some other force. If you had been exposed to them, you had to wear dark glasses and essentially have all of the curtains closed in your home, etc.

Does anybody at all know what I am describing?

Comment: I know *Blue Peter* once did a miniseries involving grey balls from outer space that possessed people, but they did so by emitting a gas rather than a light.

Comment: @F1Krazy - Sounds worthy of submission as an actual answer, rather than just a comment.

Comment: Not sure about the Blue Peter suggestion… I can’t remember any cricket ball type things but can’t completely rule it out. 

I think that towards the end of the series the way to destroy them was going to be from people playing music in a recording studio. As I remember the people who had been possessed couldn’t tolerate loud noise. The light that the brain/ball type thing might have given off could have been green also.

Comment: Sounds like it may be an episode of *The Tomorrow People*. If the affected person removed their dark glasses, were their eyes colour-reversed with black surrounding a glowing green core?

Answer (score 4):

Probably  [The Tomorrow People](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tomorrow_People).

There have been three separate series called The Tomorrow People, all of them based around the premise of young adults who start to develop telepathic powers.  It sounded like a likely match.  This would be the second version, which ran from 1992 to 1995

In the Wiki description I found the following.

> The second story, "The Living Stones", ...  featured the first use of aliens in the 1990s series, as the Tomorrow People battled a group of alien spores which had crashed near a village and possessed most of the villagers.

This part shows a ball opening up and emitting light.  I haven't watched the whole thing, I don't know if wearing dark glasses had anything to do with it.

Comment: I agree, this fits all the points. The seedpods emit green light to take over their hosts, and people who were taken over had to wear dark glasses because they became very sensitive to light (which leads to how the spores were eventually destroyed).

Answer (score 3):

*Blue Peter* once did a miniseries with a similar premise: a grey ball lands on Earth from outer space and, when approached, emits a strange gas that causes the person to become possessed by some alien force. I don't remember whether there are any other such balls, but the possessed people are able to possess others by breathing the gas into their faces.

I can't remember what it was called or when it aired, nor have I found any clips online, but I know it would have been in the early 2000s and would have aired on the BBC, so it matches most of the details you provided. Here are some other details that might jog your memory:

- The first ball falls during a cricket match, and the first person to get possessed is a player (played by presenter Matt Baker) who accidentally catches the alien ball instead of the cricket ball.
- The protagonist is female, might be an alien, and is trying to free the possessed people.
- Throughout the miniseries, there are puzzles for the protagonist (and viewers) to decipher. By taking a letter from each answer, they end up with a secret codeword - "SATURN" - that lets them activate a device that frees the possessed people.

Comment: Did Blue Peter adapt John Christopher's Tripods series?

Comment: @Andrew I don't think so. The BBC *did* [adapt the Tripods series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tripods_(TV_series)) in 1984-85, but as its own thing.

Comment: Thank you. It was just a passing thought.